# How to put search on action bar (comparison example inside)

Tags: android, xml

[image: Mine]

[image: Other]

Basically I want to get the search mode on actionbar, just like the other app.

I am not sure how the other app is implemented for the pictures (maybe listview), I make mine as gridview. The Filter I use works fine to filter the items based on name.

For anything else I forgot to post let me know and I will update asap.

grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.skypower.myapp.Grid">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:queryHint="hey">


    </SearchView>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >


    </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.skypower.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>


        <activity  android:name="com.skypower.myapp.HeroSelectionActivity"
                   android:label="hahaha"
                   android:parentActivityName="com.skypower.myapp.MainActivity" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.skypower.myapp.MainActivity" />

             />

        </activity>


        <activity  android:name="com.skypower.smartpick.Grid"
                   android:label="hahaha"
                   android:parentActivityName="com.skypower.myapp.MainActivity" >


            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                       android:value="com.skypower.myapp.MainActivity" />


        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

model:xml: (used for each grid item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe this tutorial helps? https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html

Answer (score 0):

Goto [SearchView Widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html) to know about the inbuilt widget.